# set and zip questions with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Not sure why this one works when using set and zip:

```
>>> a = ([1])
>>> b = ([2])
>>> set(zip(a,b))
{(1, 2)}
```

but this one doesn't ?.

```
>>> a = ([1],[2])
>>> b = ([3],[4])
>>> set(zip(a,b))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    set(zip(a,b))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Desired result (1,3) (2,4)

What's the right way to do this ?

Thanks!

John

Comment: The former isn't a one-tuple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It makes more sense if we look at the `zip` output:

```
>>> a = ([1]) # equivalent to [1], not a tuple
>>> b = ([2]) # equivalent to [2], not a tuple
>>> list(zip(a,b))
[(1, 2)]

>>> a = ([1],[2])
>>> b = ([3],[4])
>>> list(zip(a,b))
[([1], [3]), ([2], [4])]
```

In the first case, the list contains a tuple of ints; in the second case, it contains tuples of lists and lists are not hashable.

In the first case, if you wanted a singleton tuple containing a list, you should use `a = ([1],)` and `b = ([2],)`. If you define `a` and `b` that way, then `set(zip(a, b))` will fail like it does in the second case.

Comment: The important bit being you can only apply set to an iterable of hashable objects...

Comment: I didn't realize until now that ([1]) is a list type and not a tuple. Thanks for your explanation

Comment: The reason why it is a list and not a tuple is because the `()` are simply grouping operators if they don't contain a comma. That's why `(1)` is an integer but `(1,)` is a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform operation like this then you get the desired output.

```
a = ([1],[2])
b = ([3],[4])
zip(zip(*a),zip(*b))[0]
```

Like this ((1, 2), (3, 4)).

`zip(*a)` convert the all list in a and b tuple variable like [(1,2)] and [(3,4)].

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable ?. Probably because it's written for 2.x instead of 3.x version ?.

Answer (score 0):

You should have written this:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
```